# How to find the size of a file in a different relative directory using stat() in C?

Tags: c, macos

Here's my function to get the size of a file using stat():

```
off_t fsize(const char *filename) {                                                                                                                   
  struct stat st;                                                                                                                                        

  if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)                                                                                                                          
     return st.st_size;                                                                                                                                 

  fprintf(stderr, "Cannot determine size of %s: %s\n",                                                                                                   
         filename, strerror(errno));                                                                                                                    

  return -1;                                                                                                                                             
}
```

I can get the file size just fine by doing:

```
size = fsize ("byte.bin");
```

but when I need to get the file from a lower directory from the local directory, let's say "deps/src" directory, it stops prematurely on me with no error message that i expected:

```
size = fsize ("deps/src/byte.bin");
```

I wrote a small program that uses the function, copied the byte.bin file to a "deps/byte.bin" and called my fsize function with "deps/byte.bin" and get the error "Cannot determine size of byte.bin: No such file or directory"

If I use an absolute path like "/something/deps/byte.bin" it works.

What am I doing wrong and how show I do this for the relative path?

Comment: _Why_ does it bomb? You've presumably got the `strerror` right there, what does it say?

Comment: It doesn't print that error message like I'd think. That error msg is printed if I explicitly give it a file that doesn't exist. When I use "deps/src/byte.bin", which does exist, it gives me a malloc error in my malloc_error_break. Yet, if I copy that same file to my local dir and use "byte.bin" it runs just fine

Comment: If you get a malloc error, I'd dare to say you have a problem elsewhere which manifestates exactly here.

Comment: @glglgl but why would that occur by just changing the string value? I would think stat would throw an error message that my fsize() would return, just like when I explicitly put in a false string.

Comment: @EhevuTov: did you try this in a small program that does nothing but call `fsize()` and display results?

Comment: @EhevuTov Why not ? If your code does something it should not, and invokes undefined behavior, there's no telling what will follow, and anything could trigger bad things to happen anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm doing that now, actually. This is part of a larger SNMP agent program I'm creating. I'll let you know my results.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I wrote a small test program and I'm getting a "no such file or directory" error even though I made a copy into "deps/" dir and changed the string in the code to "deps/byte.bin"

Comment: Now that you've got a small test program, you'll stand a chance of figuring out what the problem is; run `strace -o /tmp/out -f ./test deps/byte.bin` (or however you need to call it) and look at the system calls and their return values in `/tmp/out` -- once you find the failing `stat` call, I expect the error will be clear as day.

Comment: @glglgl it's a malloc error because the file size function returns a -1 and when I malloc for -1 later, which is why I need the file size, it errors the malloc. That is not the root-cause problem however. It's this problem with not being able to use the fsize() in a different dir.

Comment: @sarnold thanks, I'm getting closer and appreciate your example tremendously, but I need to find a MacOSX equivalent. It looks like I might be able to use "trace" but not sure...

Comment: Oh, bother, sorry about that. I _think_ OS X uses the combination `ktruss` followed by `ktrace` -- or `truss` followed by `trace`. I hope that helps.

Comment: @sarnold I don't have a ktruss or ktrace and they're not in my port/software system. MacOS X is fBSD and netBSD based. Is this something I could use dtrace with? These tools are new to me but I'm excited to get to work on tracing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aha, looks like the modern equivalent is [`dtruss`](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/). :)

Comment: Assuming you deleted `byte.bin` after having copied it to `deps`: if you get "*Cannot determine size of byte.bin: No such file or directory"*" you did pass `byte.bin` to `fsize()` so it's perfectly ok you get an error indicating `byte.bin` can not be found, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I'm narrowing down the issue. It seems absolute paths work, but relative paths don't (except if the file is in the current working dir). So "/src/deps/api" works but not "deps/api" when I compile and run from "/src"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that what's happening is that you are incorrectly assuming about the working directory. A simple way to test where the working directory is would be to just write a program that simply outputs a file like `test.txt`. In many (but not all) cases, the working directory is wherever the executable file is stored. This means that if you are trying to access a file on a relative path, you will likely need to include at least one `..` in your relative path to get out of the `bin` directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree. I wish I could find out which dir stat() uses. I find the behavior odd if it uses the current working directory for just the filename, but a different cwd for a path/filename. I also ran GetCurrentDir() from unistd.h and it returned my cwd correctly. It's strange.

Comment: @EhevuTov, let me reiterate Jonathan Wood's question, then. Is `deps` a subfolder of the current working directory? If it is not, then what you have will not work because it is an incorrect relative path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said previously it was a sub directory, and it is.